# UILabel position inside custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

I have custom UITableViewCell (.h, .m and .xib file) with two UILabels. I am changing the content of UILabels and want to change their positions accordingly. When I do NSLogs after changing the position in the code it seems is working, but on screen frame of UILabel stays the same. What am I doing wrong?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   static NSString *cellIdentifierTwo = @"Cell with labels";
   CellWithTwoLabels *cell = (CellWithTwoLabels *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifierTwo];
   if (cell == nil) {
      NSArray *views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CellWithTwoLabels" owner:nil options:nil];
      for (UIView *view in views) {
         if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
            cell = (CellWithTwoLabels *)view;
         }
      }
   }
   // First UILabel
   cell.nameOfDataLabel.text = @"Region";
   // Second UILabel
   cell.valueOfDataLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:15.0];
   // Content of second UILabel
   if (self.region) {
      cell.valueOfDataLabel.text = self.region;
   }
   else {
      cell.valueOfDataLabel.text = @"Placeholder text";
   }
   // Setting the frame of second UILabel
   CGSize newSize = [cell.valueOfDataLabel.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", cell.valueOfDataLabel.font.fontName] size:cell.valueOfDataLabel.font.pointSize]];
   // Assign new size
   CGRect textFrame = cell.valueOfDataLabel.frame;
   textFrame.size  = newSize;
   textFrame.origin.x = cell.frame.size.width - textFrame.size.width - 20;
   cell.valueOfDataLabel.frame = textFrame;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableView with dynamic cell heights](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163412/uitableview-with-dynamic-cell-heights)

Comment: I've tried your code and it works well, are you sure you have your outlets connected correctly or if there is any other code that resets the label position?

Comment: Ok, the solution was to tick off the "Use Autolayout" option in the .xib file of the cell... That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the height for the cell along with the text in

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and also set numberOfLines for label = 0.